# When are two (geometric) symmetries counted as one?

Tags: geometry, symmetry, isometry

I am using the following (incomplete?) definition of a symmetry:

> A symmetry of a figure $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  is an isometry which maps $F$ to itself.

Let me illustrate my question by considering a straight line $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. I can immediatly identify two symmetries:

- The identity
- Rotation by $180°$

I notice that the symmetry given by a rotation by $360°$ is equal to the identity because every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is mapped to itself.

But what about the reflection about the axis coinciding with $S$? In this case every point $(x,y) \in S$ with $ x,y\in \mathbb{R} $ is mapped to itself. So the action on the straight line is exactly the same as the identity would do. Now my question: Is this counted as a seperate symmetry or as the same?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends on what you want to do with the line and its symmetries. Some times you want your line to have "red and green sides", some times you don't.